# Best practice "OR" and "Ternary" operators

Tags: javascript, variables, operators

When we assign a value to a variable is best practice to use the || operator or the ? operator?

Example:

OR

```
var x = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset;
```

Ternary

```
var x = "scrollX" in window ? window.scrollX : window.pageXOffset;
```

What is the best way?

Comment: What happens if `scrollX` is 0 and you use the first version?

Comment: ternary, always : more readable, less "error" prone, see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/82593/javascript-ternary-operator-vs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are not equivalent.
In the first version you check if the scrollX value 'is'. That is, if its undefined, false, null, 0, and so on.
In the second version you check if the window object has a `scrollX` property.

For example:
If you use the first one and the `scrollX` value is `0`, it will use the `pageXOffset` property value, while in version two, it will use the `scrollX` value.

Try this in the console:

```
var a = { x: 0, y: 1 };
var or = a.x || a.y;
var tern = 'x' in a ? a.x : a.y;

console.log('or: ' + or);
console.log('tern: ' + tern);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset;
```

Above method has some side effects. There is an short-circuit structure in JS in this case. Whatever the window.scrollX takes, always it will be accepted. Unless it is undefined, all result of x is window.scrollX